# How to (properly) render additional data in grid with RowExpander

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I'm trying to render some data in the rowbody in a grid (with the RowExpander plugin).
My problem is that the ol' `rowBodyTpl` isn't enough for me as this data is from Records on Stores from the record being rendered (hmmm...).

Putting it simply: Every **record** of the grid has a store in it (lets call it **Items**). So, I want to render the **record** data and some data of the **Items** records aswell.

What would be the best(ish) way of doing so?

Override the `renderer` function of the `rowexpander` plugin, override the `getAdditionalData`, or none of these?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I "solve" this problem, it might help somebody else:

I overrode the **getRowBodyFeatureData** of the rowexpander plugin, as this function not only receives the data to be applied on the template, but also the record itself, so I just `data` added the extra stores/arrays from the record.

Not sure if its the best way, but hey... at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a few years old, but here's a trick I currently use to handle this kind of situation. It takes advantage of "verbatim" blocks that XTemplates allow. These allow you to execute arbitrary code inside an XTemplate by wrapping it with `{% ... %}`. Inside those code blocks, `this` is set to the XTemplate itself. The XTemplate has an `owner` property that, in our case, references the `RowExpander` plugin itself, which, in turn, has a `grid` property to reference the grid. So, something like this allows you to add arbitrary data to the values passed into `rowBodyTpl`.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    ...
    injectRowBodyData: function(values) {
        values.MyInjectedContent = "Here's some extra data!";
    },
    plugins: [
        {
            ptype: 'rowexpander',
            rowBodyTpl: [
                '{% this.owner.grid.injectRowBodyData(value); %}',
                '<div>',
                    '<h1>{Title}</h1>',
                    '<p>{Content}</p>,
                    '<p>{MyInjectedContent}</p>',
                '</div>'
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Hhopefully Sencha will fix the plugin to provide a way to handle this in the future. But for now this works well. I tested this with v4.2.1.883, but this should work with any previous version of Ext 4. The only thing I can think of that may prevent it from working in the future is the XTemplate's `owner` property no longer being pointed to the plugin, or the plugin not having a reference to the grid with it's  `grid` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `if else` statements in `rowBodyTpl`:

**Check for ":"**

```
"<tpl if='phone == \":\"'>",
"<tpl else>",
"</tpl>"
```

**Check for empty string**

```
"<tpl if='phone == \"\"'>",
"</tpl>"
```

this sample is taken from here: [link](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261278-tpl-if-else-question)

Answer (score -1):

This is how I usually do:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
border: true,
store: 'ds',
    columns: []
    plugins: [{
            ptype: 'rowexpander',
            rowBodyTpl : ['<p><b>Title:</b>{name}<br/><b>Description:</b> {description}<br/><b>Experiment Design:</b> {experimentdesign}</p>']
    }],
    renderTo: 
});
```

Comment: How is that different from the normal rowBodyTpl?